# VBA: Error 1004 when copying data from one workbook to empty row on another

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to automate some copy and paste work, where I've got a template workbook that when filled out the user will run a macro which will copy and paste a row from the now filled template document and paste it into the next empty row of another workbook. i keep hitting an error when i run it and i'm not entirely sure how to amend the code to allow it to work

```
Sub hello()

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(61, 1), Cells(61, 6)).Select   'selects the row of data from populated template
Selection.Copy                                          'copies that row
Workbooks.Open Filename:="destination workbook file path" 'opens destination workbook that needs the date pasted into
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select  'selects the next empty row in destination workbook
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues                    'pastes values not formulas
ActiveWorkbook.Save                                     'saves destination workbook

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True                  'closes destination workbook

End Sub
```

When i run it the error occurs on the line where it selects the next empty row.

Comment: Does the sheet that was active when the destination workbook was last saved have anything in column A other than something in A1?  If not, your `End(xlDown)` will be selecting the last row in the worksheet (probably row 1048576), and the `Offset(1, 0)` will then be trying to select the row below the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `End(xlDown)` if there is nothing in the column other than something on row 1.  Use `End(xlUp)` instead:

```
Sub hello()
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Dim dstWb As Workbook
    Dim dstRng As Range

    Set srcRng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(61, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(61, 6))
    Set dstWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="destination workbook file path")
    With ActiveSheet  'Not a good idea - would be better to use With dstWb.Worksheets("specific_sheet_name")
        Set dstRng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6)
        dstRng.Value = srcRng.Value
    End With
    dstWb.Save
    dstWb.Close SaveChanges:=False 'no need to save again as far as I can see    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would Activesheet be worse than using dstWb, i thought that opening the workbook makes the first sheet active and thus OK for me to work with, apologies if it's something obvious fairly new to this.

Comment: @V.N When opening a workbook, the `ActiveSheet` will be the one that was active when it was last saved.  Do you trust your users to never save it with a different sheet active than the one you want to update?  (Even if the `ActiveSheet` was always set to `Worksheets(1)`, do you trust the users to never change the tab order of the sheets?)

Comment: Only i will have any reason to use the destination file (plus it only has one sheet in the workbook), so i doubt the other users of the template file will be messing about with it. but i understand the intention of specifying the sheet directly, i will make the amendment thank you